# how to get specific column values in array after sorting any column in datatable

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

I have html table of 4-5 columns including `id`, `name`, `description` etc...,
I have  applied [datatable](/questions/tagged/datatable) on it. I want to get `id` column data in an array if I sort `name` column. How can I get it?

P.s: Sorry for bad english.

Comment: have you tried anything ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what programming language you are using. I **assume** that you want to get that you want the list of id [based on the name sorting]

```
select id from TABLE order by name
```

I **assume** that you are using **SQL**